# How to deny a specific user to even list a specific path?

Tags: permissions

I read many QAs here, but none of them could answer me, so I decided to ask.

Let's say I've just created a new user `son`, and I want him to have `sudo` permission so he can install new packages [it's done by adding him to sudoers].

I don't want him to be able to list or read or do anything else under `/root` and `/home`, but have full access in `/home/son`. It means, he can't `ls /home` and if there is a file `/root/private/password.txt`, there is no possible way for him to know it's there.

I don't want to jail root. I don't want to change his shell to something like `rbash`. I tried some `setfacl` commands but still no success.

Comment: If someone has `sudo`, they are `root`. One way to block access to a directory would be via encrypted volumes that are unmounted when a user signs out 

Comment: The sudoers file does have granularity, so you can add specific programs for specific users without giving out the keys to the castle.  The x permission on dirs does limit scanning, but you cannot remove all read access on /home and expect /home/son to be available.